# How is array of pair<double,double> 2 times faster than two arrays of double C++

Tags: c++, caching, memory, cpu-registers, cpu-cache

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<double,double> pd;
#define x first
#define y second
#define cell(i,j,w) ((i)*(w) + (j))

class MyTimer
{
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> starter;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> ender;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        starter = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    long long getCounter() {
        ender = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(ender - starter).count();
    }
};
        
int main()
{
    const int n = 5000;
    int* value1 = new int[(n + 1) * (n + 1)];
    int* value2 = new int[(n + 1) * (n + 1)];
    double* a = new double[(n + 1) * (n + 1)];
    double* b = new double[(n + 1) * (n + 1)];
    pd* packed = new pd[(n + 1) * (n + 1)];
    MyTimer timer;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            value1[cell(i, j, n + 1)] = rand() % 5000;
            value2[cell(i, j, n + 1)] = rand() % 5000;
        }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        a[cell(i, 0, n + 1)] = 0;
        a[cell(0, i, n + 1)] = 0;
        b[cell(i, 0, n + 1)] = 0;
        b[cell(0, i, n + 1)] = 0;
        packed[cell(i, 0, n + 1)] = pd(0, 0);
        packed[cell(0, i, n + 1)] = pd(0, 0);
    }

    for (int tt=1; tt<=5; tt++)
    {
        timer.startCounter();
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                // packed[i][j] = packed[i-1][j] + packed[i][j-1] - packed[i-1][j-1] + value1[i][j]
                packed[cell(i, j, n + 1)].x = packed[cell(i - 1, j, n + 1)].x + packed[cell(i, j - 1, n + 1)].x - packed[cell(i - 1, j - 1, n + 1)].x + value1[cell(i, j, n + 1)];
                packed[cell(i, j, n + 1)].y = packed[cell(i - 1, j, n + 1)].y + packed[cell(i, j - 1, n + 1)].y - packed[cell(i - 1, j - 1, n + 1)].y + value1[cell(i, j, n + 1)] * value1[cell(i, j, n + 1)];
            }
        cout << "Time packed  = " << timer.getCounter() << "\n";

        timer.startCounter();
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                // a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-1] - a[i-1][j-1] + value2[i][j];
                // b[i][j] = b[i-1][j] + b[i][j-1] - b[i-1][j-1] + value2[i][j] * value2[i][j];
                a[cell(i, j, n + 1)] = a[cell(i - 1, j, n + 1)] + a[cell(i, j - 1, n + 1)] - a[cell(i - 1, j - 1, n + 1)] + value2[cell(i, j, n + 1)];
                b[cell(i, j, n + 1)] = b[cell(i - 1, j, n + 1)] + b[cell(i, j - 1, n + 1)] - b[cell(i - 1, j - 1, n + 1)] + value2[cell(i, j, n + 1)] * value2[cell(i, j, n + 1)];
            }
        cout << "Time separate = " << timer.getCounter() << "\n\n";
    }

    delete[] value1;
    delete[] value2;
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] packed;
}
```

So I'm computing a 2D prefix table (Summed Area Table). And I notice the property in the title.

When using CUDA nvcc compiler (with -O2) using the command line or Visual Studio Release mode , **the result is 2x faster** (separate takes 200ms, packed takes 100ms) the first run, but only 25% faster in subsequent run (this is because `value2[]` is cached after the first loop). In my actual program with more steps of calculation (computing SAT is just step 1), it's always 2x faster since `value1[]` and `value2[]` have definitely been evicted from cache.

I know packed array is faster because modern Intel **CPU read 32-64 bytes into cache at once**. So by packing both array together, it can **read both data in 1 main memory (RAM) access instead of 2**. But **why is the speedup so high**? Along with memory access, the CPU still has to perform 6 additions, 2 subtractions, and 1 multiply per loop. 2x speedup from halving memory access is **100% improvement efficiency** (Amdahl Law), **the same as if those add/mult operations** didn't exist. How is it possible?

I'm certain it has something to do with CPU pipelining, but can't explain more thoroughly. Can anyone explain this further in terms of instruction latency/memory access latency/assembly? Thank you.

The code doesn't use any GPU, so any other good compiler should give the same 2x speedup as nvcc. On g++ 9.3.0 (`g++ file.cpp -O2 -std=c++11 -o file.exe`), it's also 2x speedup. CPU is Intel i7-7700

I've run this program [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) and [here2](https://repl.it/languages/cpp11) with command line arguments `-O2 -std=c++11`, it also shows 1.5-2x speedup. **Use n = 3000**, bigger and it won't run (free VM service, afterall). So it's not just my computer

Comment: Did you compile your code with compiler optimizations enabled? If not, do that now and then benchmark again. Benchmarking unoptimized debug builds is rather pointless.

Comment: yes, it's with -O2 as well as release mode. I have tested it with both nvcc and g++ 9.3, and in both case the result is 2x faster

Comment: Where is pair used in your code?

Comment: @S.M. -- It is here: `typedef pair<double,double> pd;` -- But it's not really your fault -- it's those crazy macros I've seen lately from so many posters.  Not only is the type hidden by a macro, it is hidden by a two-letter, lower case macro.

Comment: Got different benchmark [Here](https://quick-bench.com/q/WNm3wx2ORj9uZm19C1_3k3jOLLM) (Have to reduce size to avoid timeout though)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you. It is really difficult to discover the pair in a plain text.

Comment: Added other (slower) version with 2 loops [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/mM-uUoR94pzsgIzl8GcA1wLztgU).

Comment: CPU prediction and caches should be taken into account. The array of pairs is a single memory block. Two arrays are two memory blocks.

Comment: @S.M. yes I mentioned that in the bolded text

Comment: @Jarod42 can you enable optimization ? In the code I see that you set "DoNotOptimize" in the setting. Also I'm not sure how those benchmark function at QuickBench work, so it might behave differently

Comment: @HuyĐứcLê: Optimization are on (Optim = 03). `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);` is a trick to avoid the compiler to remove completely the loop as no effect (As we modify global here, it should not be needed, but it doesn't hurt anyway).

Comment: With gcc ([Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/mm83WUSxKZnhIgMX79BH7H9AtFU)), (other benchs use clang), both version are comparable.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tested on 2 different sites (edit 2) which give the same 2x speedup. Maybe something is done differently on quickbench.com, such as older CPU ?

Comment: @HuyĐứcLê: You might provide link with shared code instead of just main site.

Comment: @Jarod42 I just copy my code from the post to those site and press run. Nothing changed. Command line -O2 -std=c++11 and set n = 3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the access latency of different level of memory, from L1 cache -> main memory (RAM).

Data in L1 cache takes ~~5 cycle to access, while data from RAM takes 50-100cycle. Meanwhile, add/sub/mult operations takes 3-5 cycles.

Therefore, the dominating limiter of performance is main memory access. So by reducing the number of main memory request by half, performance almost doubles